# Thousand separator in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

Is there a way to show the below value like 1,82,90,829 in scorecards in Google Data Studio? I searched a lot but I couldn't find an option to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an option to format scorecard number to support currency format in thousands.

Closer meaningful solution I found was using Indian Currency format with Compact numbers. Choose your currency as per your requirement.

[image]

Total Sales in Trillion:

[image]

Comment: This workaround might work when the amount is just a few thousand but it won't work when it is in millions. Have tried this with millions?

Comment: Updated the answer with Trillion value, I guess it works.